# circles cover triangle

Tags: geometry

Please help to solve this question:

three circles cover triangle.  Can they still  cover any triangle with decreased sides ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to be more descriptive. How do they cover the triangle? I can place 3 huge circles that each cover the triangle. Yes, they will still cover with decreased sides.

Comment: Do you have a diagram of what you're taking about? Do the 3 circles have a common point? Does every 2 circles have another common point on the side of the triangle? Does every circle pass through a vertex of the triangle?

Answer (score 4):

Consider a triangle with side lengths (1, 1, 1.99999) it is very nearly a straight line and can be covered using 3 circles of radius 1/3.

Assuming that we are not allowed to move them, the same three circles would not cover the triangle with side lengths (1, 1, 1).